# How can I increase the width of Firefox's (Quantum, v. 57+) url bar and make the navbar overflow?

Tags: css, firefox, flexbox

I have many addons and what I orginally wanted was an additional "addon bar" (like [the "Addon bar restored"](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/the-addon-bar/)) where I could put my addons' buttons. Unfortunately, Firefox Quantum (version 57+) only accepts WebExtensions or CSS code in the [userChrome.css](https://www.userchrome.org) file. I'm trying this second option: modifying the .css file to make the url bar's width as big as I want and make the overflow of the navbar create a "second" bar (or rather, a second line) underneath it, where the overflowing addons' buttons will stay.

With the following code, I can increase the `urlbar-container` width to what I want, but `nav-bar` doesn't overflow and therefore the addons' buttons don't overflow to a second row.

```
#urlbar-container {
    min-width: 1000px !important;
}

#nav-bar {
    //dsplay: block;
    overflow-x: visible !important;
    overflow-y: visible !important;
    overflow: visible !important;
    max-height: 500px !important;       
}
```

Does anyone know how can I: 1- increase the width of the `urlbar-container` and 2- make the `nav-bar` overflow so that instead of hiding the overflowing buttons it will display them in a new row underneath it?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working code:

```
#urlbar {
    width: 100%;
}

#urlbar-container {
    //min-width: 1000px !important;
    flex: 0 0 80% !important; /*change the size to what you like*/
}

#nav-bar-customization-target {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap !important;
    align-items: center;
    align-content: center;
}

#nav-bar {
    min-height: 80px;
    height: 100%;
}
```

It works well, but I wish I could substitute rule `min-height: 80px` to something less hacky in `#nav-bar`. I tried `2em` and `200%`, but only pixels worked. This is bad because if I decrease the window's width, new flex rows are created, but they are cropped out due to the height restriction. Am I missing something?